# Run Cucumber feature in Jar on Linux server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, cucumber

I've an application which runs some tests using Cucumber. I'm able to run it from my Eclipse with the following configuration:

[image] [image]

I want to deploy it to a Linux server though. I built a jar with `mvn clean package` and on my server I'm trying to run it with the following command but it doesn't work:

`java -jar test-tool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dcucumber.options="external-features" -ea`

How can I run these tests in a jar from a Linux command line?